# What does it mean by "formal identity" in the sixth line from the top on page 79 from Koblitz's p-adic Numbers, p-adic Analysis, and Zeta-Functions.

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

[image]

What does it mean by "formal identity" in the sixth line from the top? The text comes from page 79 from Koblitz's p-adic Numbers, p-adic Analysis, and Zeta-Functions. Any explanation is appreciated.

Comment: In such contexts "formal" means an identity in the ring of power series, i.e. when you don't even think about substituting anything in place of $X$ or $Y$, and thus don't need to worry about convergence (well, may be convergence w.r.t. $I$-adic topology). Here we are further using the fact we know from real analysis that the series do converge in the topology of the numberline. And even more so, satisfy this relation. Then we use the fact that an identity of real power series, valid in a set with non-empty interior, implies the same identity in the ring of formal power series.

Comment: "Formal" means that one is working with *formal* power series, where equality means equality of corresponding coefficients (vs. *functional* power series, where one has to be concerned with convergence, etc), analogous to formal vs. functional polynomials. Formal power series are ubiquitous in combinatorial applications, serving as *generating "functions"* for combinatorial sequences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They refer to the identity $\log((1+x)(1+y))=\log(1+x)+\log(1+y)$ in $\mathbb{Q}[[X,Y]]$, where $\log(1+x) := \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1} \frac{x^n}{n}$ in $\mathbb{Q}[[X]]$.

One way to prove this identity is to use $\exp(x+y)=\exp(x) \exp(y)$, where $\exp(x):=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!}$. Or, one uses the corresponding log-identity for complex power series (for $|x|,|y|<1$) and then compares coefficients.